# failed at `&:extend(.clearfix all);`

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'm working with a clone of a existing (and working) Symfony2 project.
It is using Bootstrap-2.2.2, so I've installed `Less` to dump the assetics:

```
sudo npm install less
```

and it is installed, but when I try to dump the assetics:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=dev --no-debug
```

I'm getting this error:

```
[Exception]                                                                  
parse error: failed at `&:extend(.clearfix all);` /home/user/server/project/app/../web/css/../vendor/bootstrap-2.3.1/less/mixins.less on l  
ine 643
```

I've already found this issue on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11892), and I've upgraded to newer version:

I've download the `3.1.1` version in the `web/` directory, and in the base template (`base.html.twig`):

```
    {% javascripts output='compiled/*'
        'vendor/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'
        'bootstrap-2.0.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'
        'js/twitter.js'
        'js/main.js' %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}" onerror="redconvive.onErrorEvent(this)"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
```

to:

```
    {% javascripts output='compiled/*'
        'vendor/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'
        'bootstrap-3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'
        'js/twitter.js'
        'js/main.js' %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}" onerror="redconvive.onErrorEvent(this)"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
```

but I'm getting same output. Also tried to reinstall `less`, removing `node_modules/` and again: `sudo npm install less`. But nothing changes. Any idea of how to solve it?

Comment: `extend` is a somewhat new addition to less. I know [at least one implementation](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/356) hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - All right. So maybe it can be resolved installing an older version of Bootstrap. Isn't it?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo npm install -g less`?

Comment: @ShuheiKagawa - I've tried, but same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved changing the `leafo/lessphp` version in `composer.json`:

From:

```
 "leafo/lessphp": "~0.3"
```

to

```
"leafo/lessphp": "~0.3.9"
```